# How to remove htaccess path in URL?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have a website made ​​in joomla that works with friendly URL. To have better control of URL, installed a SEF component, I enabled the "mod_rewrite" and htaccess. However, I can not navigate through links on my site whenever I click on something, the url changes but the page always remains in the home. And when access to the main page, my URL is the path of htaccess. Example...

Normal URL without htaccess and mod_rewrite: `www.mysite.com`

With htacess and mod_rewrite ON: `www.mysite.com/var/www/html/mysite.com/web`

If you want to see my htaccess file I posted it [here](http://pastebin.com/9bVNx6hA).

Could anyone help me to solve, please?

Answer (score 0):

That is the stock joomla htaccess file.  This should not affect your url.

What is the SEF component?

Have you asked your host about this?

Comment: The SEF component is called "AceSEF". I will try to contact the host to see if there are any problems from them.